# Connection account when moving a power automate to production?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, powerapps, power-automate

What alternatives exist for connection account when moving a power automate or logic app to production? For logic apps managed identities could be used but what if the system/workload to connect to is not among [supported ones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity?tabs=consumption#where-you-can-use-a-managed-identity) like for example Microsoft Teams? I've seen talk generically about service accounts but are these just standard Office 365 user accounts being used exclusively by applications/services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only current option is to create a dedicated user account with appropriate licenses for the platforms you need to interact with (e.g., Microsoft Teams, SharePoint, etc.) and use that account as a "service account" (which is a user account uses only by application or a service) to create the required connections in power automate or for your logic app.

It would really be great if Microsoft defined a way to create real service accounts for this purpose, in other words objects that do not require any license to interact with any platform or workload (such as SharePoint or Teams) and that cannot be used by a real end-user to interact with those platforms or workloads, something like service principals in azure.